(EF Core 8) System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'x => new Foo{ } ' could not be translated
....Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable'.
I have some code that generates an expression that I then try to execute against a postgres db, that I've scaffolded using CLI tools.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design - 8.0.10
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL - 8.0.10

I'm trying to make projections from an underlying db structure using Expression<> e.g.
public static Expression<Func<Psiproductpart, ES_PRODUCT>> MakeExpresion()
{
    return record =>
        new ES_PRODUCT()
        {
            oid = record.Oid,
            p_product_programpressinformationrecords =
                record
                    .Programpressinforecords
                    .AsQueryable()
                    .Select(ES_WONPROGRAMPRESSINFORMATIONRECORD.MakeExpresion()).ToList(),
        };
}

where Psiproductpart is the type of a record in the db, and ES_PRODUCT is some projection, the above code works, where I have 1:N relationships.
The issue I seem to have is trying to make 1:1 relationships work, using the LinqKit 1.3, the expressions look like this.
public static Expression<Func<Wonregionalprogcertification, ES_WONREGIONALPROGRAMCERTIFICATION>> Projection()
{
    return x => new ES_WONREGIONALPROGRAMCERTIFICATION()
    {
        rpc_certification = ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION.Projection().Invoke(x.RpcIdCertificationNavigation),
    };
}

where ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION.Projection is defined to be this (for the moment):
public static Expression<Func<Wonprogramcertification?, ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION?>> Projection()
{
    
    return x => new ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION()
    {
    };
}

but EF Core seems to choke, presumably on the LinqKit invoke?

Well, it is solveable, but do you really need this, when you can do the following: AsDto() example

in my setup each "modelto" (in the terms of the AsDTo() example) has its own projection expression, it looks basically the same as the other example, but why does EF choke on it?

Because you need at least ROGRAMPRESSINFORMATIONRECORD.MakeExpresion().Expand()

that seems to work, but by magic, you've changed the line that actually seemed to work, and now the line that didnt work, works....hmmmm....is there somewhere that explains whats going on (I know VERY high level)

@SvyatoslavDanyliv and as soon as I add some simple predicates around testing for null, it fails, which means....I don't know what I'm doing, so I think I could do with reading up on it, any suggestions?

In your case C# Compiler generates Expression Tree .Select(ES_WONPROGRAMPRESSINFORMATIONRECORD.MakeExpresion()) - that's all. No one called your methods, that's why Expand() exists. LinqKit searches for Expand in tree, invokes your methods and then combines expressions.

the function was called before, its not clear to me whats going on. I'll go and look at LinqKit (or somewhere else if thats better?)

Not called but recorded. Put breakpoints into the methods.

adding breakpoints is hard, as its difficult to distinguish between the function that returns the expression and the func in the expression. if I comment out the various bits it chokes on, and remove the expand I get a list of ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION objects, I only have 1 call to the ESP_PROGRAMCERTIFICATION constructor, so something has presumably called it somehow.

Can you show your LINQ query?

not very easily, I believe you, I'm just struggling to get my head around whats going on and am now wrestling with some weird problem where I cant test a field on a projected type without some weird error.

When you return e => e.SomeMethod(Some.MakeExpression) C# compiler builds Expression Tree with thsese methods, notning called inside expression body.

Funny enough I ran into this issue 2 hours ago. Here is my original troublemaker snippet.
 var recordsToDelete = context.Folders
        .Where(folder => !existingFiles.Contains(Path.Combine(folder.RootPath, $"{folder.FolderName}.zip")))
        .ToList();

What it does: in my Case EFCore was not able to translate string and Path.Combine directly into SQL thats why I had to call it as .AsEnumerable() so I bring it directly into memory and let it client side handle this. my fixed code looked like this:
var recordsToDelete = context.Folders
.AsEnumerable() // Bring records into memory for comparison
.Where(folder =>
{
    // Normalize the path for the folder record for comparison.
    var dbFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(folder.RootPath, $"{folder.FolderName}.zip"));
      

    // Check if the database path exists in the set of existing files.
    return !existingFiles.Equals(dbFilePath);
})
.ToList();

So for a short way which applies to your specific case: EFCore has issues translating certain types directly into SQL Statements. Use .AsEnumerable to let it be handeled on the clientside. With this insight it should work

the objective is to not use client side LINQ at all, I don't really have any code that needs to be client side, this is a small piece in a larger, effectively mechanism to generate SQL. I used to have a very old version that did work on some previous version of EF, I'm struggling to make this work now though.

In this case @MrDatKookerellaLtd Invoke might be the troublemaker here. Have to tried to avoid using it and inline the properties you need or create expressions that are fully contained? and with this i mean fully? you mentioned 1:1 works but 1:N not can you give me here more detail on the behaviour?

Added note: try to avoid .ToList() this can be wonky in ensuring that everything is non-client side but thats just a side note
